# Counting MySQL records with a LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, count, while-loop

As I am trying to count the number of records in a table, even when the SQL statement has a `LIMIT` into it, overall it works, however something weird happens, the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM posts
        ORDER BY post_date DESC
        LIMIT 5";

// ... mysql_query, etc

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // ... HTML elements, etc
    echo $row['post_title'];

    // ... HTML elements, etc

    echo $row['count']; // this displays the number of posts (which shows "12").
}
```

Although, when displaying through the `while` loop, it displays this:

> Notice: Undefined index: post_title in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/index.php on line 55

If I remove the `COUNT(*) AS count`, everything will display perfectly... how come it's doing this?

Comment: why are you limiting a select query which only returns 1 result?

Comment: I am sure `$count=5;` will suit you most of time.

Comment: I guess you weren't reading properly...

Comment: I guess you weren't writing properly

Comment: I said there are 12 records, I hardly said it's returning 1 result..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use `COUNT(*)` to count the number of rows (for a lot of reasons).  Write out your full query, and add [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) right after `SELECT`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, title FROM foo LIMIT 5;
```

Then, after that query executed (right after), run:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

That will return the number of rows the original `SELECT` would have returned if you didn't have the `LIMIT` on the end (accounting for all joins and where clauses).

It's not portable, but it's very efficient (and IMHO the right way of handling this type of problem).

Comment: (Note: not portable means you can't use this on other databases. See @JohnB's answer for how to do this on practically any relational databases)

Comment: @Mike: true.  But it should be noted that the `count(*)` approach there is significantly less efficient (on complex queries it will take a very long time).  If you **need** to support multiple databases, it's the only way.  But if you're only on MySQL you should really use this...

Comment: Hi ircmaxell, just wanted to know how you run `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` with PHP? Do you have to re-execute a new query with just that? (I'm using PDO). Thanks a lot

Comment: Beware: according to [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows), those functions are _deprecated_ as of MySQL 8.0.17. They're suggesting to `executing your query with LIMIT, and then a second query with COUNT(*) and without LIMIT to determine whether there are additional rows.`

Comment: @ircmaxell is My hero!

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` does not do anything here because you're selecting a single scalar. The error is shown because you are not selecting the post title, so it is not in the `$row` hash.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `COUNT()` is an aggregate function. You will have to do two separate queries in order to get both the count of rows in the table and separate records.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found this article: http://www.mysqldiary.com/limited-select-count/
best way (especially for big tables) is using it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM (SELECT 1 FROM posts
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    LIMIT 5) t
```

now it returns a number between 0 and 5

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the `SELECT` statement to return only `COUNT(*) AS count`. If you want more columns returned, you have to specify them in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: In the OP's case doing so would represent the same table row count as a column value for 5 rows. Without a GROUP BY the result set makes little sense. It should be two queries. One to get the count, one to get the data. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

By including `COUNT(*) AS count` you've removed the actual columns that you want to get the information from.  Try using

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM posts ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

That query will accomplish both things you're trying to do in one query, but really, **these should be broken out into 2 separate queries**.  What is the overall purpose for having a COUNT in the query?  It should be done a different way.

Comment: This isn't a good answer actually. You're going to be getting back a messy mix of information - the same total count of rows in your table as a value for each row. You should do this in two queries.

Comment: @Mike (and the other guy that down-voted this answer): Mitch isn't recommending doing `SELECT *, COUNT(*)`, he was just trying to illustrate what the OP was trying to do in only one query, instead of 2, which of course would make more sense.  Mitch says that in the bottom of his answer.  +1 Mitch.

Comment: I guess if you want to be pedantic, this answers the OP question, but obviously the "best" answer should be the one that answers the question AND guides the OP to do the "right" thing... @Mitch didn't actually give an "easier" way, while other posts did (@ircmaxell, @nalroff). I -1 this and +1 the "best" answers to encourage the OP to think twice about doing the right thing (hopefully OP will learn more about aggregate functions some other day)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up an aggregate function `COUNT()` with a standard selection. You can't get an accurate post title without a GROUP BY clause in your aggregate query. The easiest thing you should do is to do this two queries - one for your count, the other for your post information. Also, there's no sense in using `LIMIT` on an aggregate function with no other columns in your (omitted) `GROUP BY` - the current query will always return one row.

Answer (score 0):

**What everyone is trying to say is that you should opt to use 2 separate queries instead of 1 single one.**

1) get row count of table

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM posts;
```

2) get last 5 rows of table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts
        ORDER BY post_date DESC
        LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$sql = "
     SELECT COUNT( po.id ) AS count, p.post_title
     FROM posts p
     JOIN posts po
     GROUP BY p.post_title
     ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
     LIMIT 5
";
```

Important is to JOIN the same table, but name the table differently. Do not forget GROUP BY, must be used.