# Select2 pagination with Ajax Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter, jquery-select2

Currently i am using below method to implement infinite scroll/pagination in select2.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#district').select2({
    placeholder: '--- Select District---',
    ajax: {
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page_limit: limit_rows,
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1; 
            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * limit_rows) < data.total
                }
            };
        },
        cache: false
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
    $pglm = $this->input->get("page_limit");
            $page_lim = (empty($pglm) ? 10 : $pglm);
            $pg = $this->input->get("page");
            $page =  (empty($pg) ? 0 : $pg);
            $sira = $page * $page_lim;
$cnt=$this->db->query("select * from districtMst");
$filteredValues=$this->db->query("select id,name as text from districtMst LIMIT $sira , $page_lim ;")->result_array();

echo json_encode(array(
            'incomplete_results' => false,
            'items' => $filteredValues,
            'total' => count($cnt) // Total rows without LIMIT on SQL query
        ));
```

Above is working perfectly well as i needed. I just want to know if there is any way to remove the count query to count total number of rows. i.e. every time the page data will be called there will be two queries will be fired which seems not a good idea for enterprise applications, so i am wondering if there is any better way to achieve the same results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i've the same issue, do you have solutions?

Comment: You can use the MySQL SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS keyword. [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925529/counting-mysql-records-with-a-limit)